# Infer types from key value pairs, where the values are function signatures?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm creating a mapping like function that is going to turn an object like this:

```
const configObject: ConfigObject = {
    a: {
        oneWay: (value: string) => 99,
        otherWay: (value: number) => "99"
    },


    b: {
        oneWay: (value: number) => undefined,
        otherWay: () => 99
    }
}
```

into:

```
{
    foos: {
        a: {
            convert: (value: string) => 99,
        },
        b: {
            convert: (value: number) => undefined
        }
    },


    bars: {
        a: {
            deconvert: (value: number) => "99",
        },
        b: {
            deconvert: () => 99;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is around enforcing the function parameter and return types, based on the ConfigItem's signatures.

The way I'm doing it looks like this:

```
interface ConfigItem<P, Q> {
    oneWay: (value: P) => Q;
    otherWay: (value: Q) => P;
}

type ConfigObject = Record<string, ConfigItem<any, any>>; //This is right, I believe. 
// any is explicitly an OK type for the ConfigItems to have. 

interface Foo<A, B> {
    convert: (a: A) => B;
}

interface Bar<A, B> {
    deconvert: (b: B) => A;
}

interface MyThing<T extends ConfigObject> {
    foos: Record<keyof T, Foo<any, any>> //These are wrong - they should use the types as defined by the config object
    bars: Record<keyof T, Bar<any, any>>
}
```

I later implement a function to create a MyThing like:

```
function createMyThing<T extends ConfigObject>(configObject: T): MyThing<T> {
    //I would use Object.entries, but TS Playground doesn't like it. 
    const keys = Object.keys(configObject);
    return {
        foos: keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
            return {
                ...acc,
                [key]: {
                    convert: configObject[key].oneWay
                }
            }
        }, {} as Record<keyof T, Foo<any, any>>), //Again problematic 'any' types. 

        bars: keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
            return {
                ...acc,
                [key]: {
                    deconvert: configObject[key].otherWay
                }
            };

        }, {}) as Record<keyof T, Bar<any, any>>

    };
}
```

Now this code works:

```
const configObject: ConfigObject = {
    a: {
        oneWay: (value: string) => 99,
        otherWay: (value: number) => "99"
    },


    b: {
        oneWay: (value: number) => undefined,
        otherWay: () => 99
    }
}
const myThing = createMyThing(configObject); 

console.log(myThing.foos.a.convert("hello"));  
console.log(myThing.foos.b.convert("hello"));  //No type enforcement!
```

But we don't have any type enforcement, due to those any statements.

How would I modify my code to make this work?

[Full TypeScript playground here.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=72&ssc=2&pln=60&pc=1#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAQogztAKgJ4AO0APAAoA0aAigHxoDeIAviBDAiugGID2fUgEFqGBszSS0yPuABucSAC40ACkQqhASjQBeBhgDcwNmChwkqTIljDR44FLQATaDPmKVqgEYqMO-TQhY1MOC240AFkCPAALCABzUjw0aAAPGHBnbDQAYVl4UASAeW8AKzdIByd4AWwVACU3PlhnUgBraAI%20eDQ8an5BRHACamGCOjpHKW8berQmmVaOrp6%200RtScbGRyZMQA7CuK3zwQoSASRgAWwpqeiZpyVloAHVEAi85RAAbAFdoCpyAEGDRjE4%20JBYnB3p81N9-oDaCC0OQQiBIMR0KdzqUKshIHoFs1lthILBEtQcUUrtBbts0ONJsYDvA-uACaBZNJYNBEDBonFEslUhloFkctSSuVKnRVO5cTKCSo8FoVIL4uAkngHCAnO4yWhOgQcro0HjKgA6Y3YeUFIoWglacFSXmQP6wcCPJ5ONC1PjzG2W3nOP6oVTqZDIajGlESX0Jt0er3xhNptCWzMoaM%209NOADaxoAuipU3n0%204FLBlNJ7dL8ZBC10i5aXrDc%20W0GxO12O5IWNRGCxGTlFi02sa1v00IMtiMdhM6FpKHq07NYIGuthg9BQ%20HI9GjV0433fUnPY8e05M5bsyur1ImwQS5eH77XJXPLWzg6lY3i62UIwh8p7pt2nYsCyYGDiwOg4MSSwTqsvTTlgtgMkyUw%20pB%20wgAahIKr%20DYqFKjqEmaZYaK%20CZth8Xy-ACKhkhSWoogAnGx95ppC0KwLC9GIio4B-Nc3hwCiABEHESdhK6rpIvjUb6tFwqoCKMWgwmieJegMOyriFOAu5cTRQF8XRajsWx2G4cA%20FoNcMSagkRLILy-LQBqiR2j%209aVM6aB4bI2B8D80CWj8fAJKojlClqlr%20tuiCWp%201aqBJ0I-JFElaAFgUGqF4WRdFsXOQldSWt4KWyFWkDpZl2W5YYkgAPQtQAcnwaCYiQqRnC0qDXOKkAAIRAA)

[Second attempt at a solution using the `infer` keyword](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=34&ssc=47&pln=34&pc=50#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAQogztAKgJ4AO0APAAoA0aAigHxoDeIAviBDAiugGID2fUgEFqGBszSS0yPuABucSAC40ACkQqhASjQBeBhgDcwNmChwkqTIljDR44FLQATaDPmKVqgEYqMO-TQhY1NgSGJ0AHFoSABJcHA4QhIhUgANBl00NLRoAA8YcGdsNQBhWXhQAHNYmABbUgh4ODQ8akRwAjotAH48FUSFWEM0EHCSNGi4hKSIjHTM7NyC6CKS1XLwSpr60g6CaiaWvG60PoHoIZGQM05LdABZAjwACwgq0jxlwuK0Te2APLeABWbkg1AA0t9Vr8ANbQAh8eCtBxOeACbAqABKbj4sGcpAh1H4gim8USsGS0FSeAA2hCALp0ahkmaUuafelMuh0RxSbw2TFoHEyfGE0Q2UisilUmlc5mTGLk2YkeZ0xk83mhdjmLhWf7VWrQBpUWioqSyaAAdUQBC8ckQABsAK7QFTkAIMGjGJx8SAvOA2u1qB0ut20T1ocghMYRP4VapA0HISB6YW4sXYSCwd7UA07Y17TrtTo84w3eDO8Ap0CyaSwaCIGBPV7vT7QtbxraJkFgyEduEIpEo1TuQG9lMqPBaFQtt7gD5tNAQhwgJzuLNoeEEEpZJNggB02+wo4TVX3Ka0PqkDcgztg4CYa6cUnRfCFx4PDecztQqnUyDINQ26RhIL7gbe96PmB4GwWgB4ISgQF8nB4G0tuDIqDBqFwe4QzKNIZ4XpA6EIgyB6WkGKE4VIbA0WgdGwSw1CMCwaA4OmooEkSaAklKSpsrKnIaiyAkyhy6rct01DUU4AqwB+CLYF+0A-n+AFAVuCKgbJsGQQ+T70U4CEHkhlC6ThpEEJhhlGeBrh4Z4hHdueE4kRhFH+oGtoWahjE4Sw5ZwcxTBsRxIp4txEq2NKKrUsJTKidM4mqglmpaDJ1GBSYNwbqmY49smBH5sRabYRotngZRtr2k6roqFmOYLpGACcLXmXBfoBrAQa1WGAzOnU3hwJGABEbWjVl5nPpIviVS+1XBqoob1Wg4CDcNsCRlWriVIkzgdbBXXeUtrUtVlOUgHlaB1M885VGmyANk20Bzu8p4ucRV6jMAG58I60AHo6fBVKot2tguB5vspiAHo5sCQKoo0Bo6wOjVo32jH9ANAyDYN3e8UMYge3hw7I+FIyjaMYyMAD0tMAMovHwzqOs4uSwLAeK-bI2D-YDwOg+D90k4KpkHg55OKKoACMNNoEAA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing you should consider is to not set `configObject` type to `ConfigObject`, because you lose the structure of the object. Create concrete interface which extends `ConfigObject` instead:

```
interface ConcreteConfigObject extends ConfigObject{
    a: ConfigItem<string, number>;
    b: ConfigItem<number, undefined>;
}
```

In `MyThing` to get rid of `any`s you can extract types from `configObject` with combining several TS features:

- [`Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst) - Constructs a tuple type of the types of the parameters of a function type T
- [`ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) - Constructs a type consisting of the return type of function T
- [`Index types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) - With index types, you can get the compiler to check code that uses dynamic property names. For example, to pick a subset of properties
- [`Mapped Types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#mapped-types) - Mapped types allow you to create new types from existing ones by mapping over property types

With above we extract argument and return types from `oneWay` and `otherWay` methods to set into `Foo<A, B>` and `Bar<A, B>`:

```
interface MyThing<T extends ConfigObject> {
    foos: MyThingFoo<T>;
    bars: MyThingBar<T>;
}

type MyThingFoo<T extends ConfigObject> = {
    [k in keyof T]: Foo<Parameters<T[k]["oneWay"]>[0], ReturnType<T[k]["oneWay"]>>;
}

type MyThingBar<T extends ConfigObject> = {
    [k in keyof T]: Bar<ReturnType<T[k]["otherWay"]>, Parameters<T[k]["otherWay"]>[0]>;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4CCAaZAIQD5kBvAKGWuQXRADdowAuZACjjZwEpkBeUoQDcFAL4UKoSLEQpCcKLgIlyVGgBMIdRszbsARm0J9ByHKIlTw0eEmQBZAJ4AVABagA5lhfIIAD0gQDQBnZABhehhgTwB5AwArbTBSShpkGEwQtmd3LwxsF2JRdINFbMdXDxBPBSUiy0kwJwAHFFzqzwKfP0CIYLDIkGi4xOTSfjV0gG0Aa2RQZFmIJ3QYZBcAXTZugAVFOABbCBkQnznN6YAieggAdTgnK83iaYAGTYIAJROAVygQC5WhBzrNLjcQPdHs9iMVxE1gZU8jU6j0AkFQhEojF4kkECkBFMaHMFiAlis1httkRFFgfmB-oDgaDwegwG5oA8ni8CPsoEcTtAzi4Ltc2RyoFyYe8Xo0KM02ljhjixvjCT86FANFgQmAoF4CEMRgBJSCHLBwEBOAiWpyw0TWGR2FBGmKmiDm3YEACKqXU1FuXP0DDgABtfhA2LtTKRvSUaOLOY9g2GI2xvTHkLs5dJbHIlQgoILXaM8WBehjBtjS8kidQuEqTWadXqDcgQL9DgZoHDSmwS+7zR2u9ACL9ghBopCNHCrDBx-jgPRaEW4JAOl40X0Bo2VWXiOwdCNcck2C4eDkqpuinXaPRdeSnGFJif8QA6ZZPw-V19gHgO9IiwZAFb3STJ0AqT8QjfIsNF+JB2E4BAEAIT9MzSdJMOoIDGVArDMLfQjEBQ-18KwuYVmpDCyJou9dCgVg6OPVUwAopxNjfQNHlI2jqAkXjkH4-CxAIMgxGQOAwg3GpuiKHg8EkMiyigSCVmg2D4IgRDiNQlZ0J4-CcJA6iBOQQi3x0gzaLYqirNMrQdCYBi2CPPdkhszj2STJw7LIoTaLEADhNE8TJKRTpUTkhTSMC+EKB0B9XJrfF+3oQtix-FjCRMhsTPSLinBTcNI2QXV9RqTMAE5KoUsjE0lZMOBDYq2GHbsoEzK5qquGLotIow8IDSEgya1MSra6BM3HLQpwgDRavw+qRvYKrKpi8QHQS8tDivGpCXStcIGkzxv2VZK-wdAB6S7kEgXUvAoHbkU8N9wOguA30c5h2CuDlQ1DdArn-ZBro4MqvB4ABaUgJqgR7dpe5T3rfBz6CcsB2AARmB0H2FhvhodK1sanh57XqyN8DE+tHvt+iB-sBnGboAUSgKB0CgbgoE8Tt+nLBUUEpAByOmGauIWFjCEA2QkkIQhiEA4AMUMUDAdBkBaA5jhkZBKQF5AhdhoWgA)

P.S. Extracting types from T looks ugly and there can be done some optimizations, I've just written it explicitly for illustration purpose.

Comment: P.S.S. There is only one issue with this solution. In `configObject.b` method `otherWay` has no argument at all. Is this a typo or how should it be converted into Bar without an argument?

Comment: Re your P.S.S - that type should be `undefined` . It's an interesting edge case.

Comment: In that case, for example, calling `myThing.bars.b.deconvert(2)` will throw `Error: Argument type of '2' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'` which is correct, but isn't it more accurate to prevent passing arguments into `deconvert` at all?

Comment: Thanks - it looks like you are right on the money with those utility types- I didn't know they exist.

Answer (score 2):

In Typescript it is possible to extract type signature from an existing value with `typeof`:

```
const configObject = {
    a: {
        oneWay: (value: string) => 99,
        otherWay: (value: number) => "99"
    },


    b: {
        oneWay: (value: number) => undefined,
        otherWay: () => 99
    }
};

type ConfigObject = typeof configObject
```

Based on `ConfigObject`, you can create `MyThing` like:

```
type MyThing = {
    foos: { [K in keyof ConfigObject]: { convert: ConfigObject[K]['oneWay']}}
    bars: { [K in keyof ConfigObject]: { deconvert: ConfigObject[K]['otherWay']}}
}
```

For completeness `createMyThing` may be typed as:

```
function createMyThing(configObject: ConfigObject) {
    const keys = Object.keys(configObject) as (keyof ConfigObject)[];

    return {
        foos: keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
            return {
                ...acc,
                [key]: {
                    convert: configObject[key].oneWay
                }
            }
        }, {}),

        bars: keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
            return {
                ...acc,
                [key]: {
                    deconvert: configObject[key].otherWay
                }
            };

        }, {}),
    } as MyThing;
}
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=44&ssc=2&pln=20&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmB5ARgKwgY2CgF4pRI4kp9FVNcDgAoJ86AWRABUALFBNCSgBvJlHFQkcOAGcAXCKgBtANJR+UANYQQlWLXTY8hALoLh1RADcIAJ2AL4yQw0KqTSgOSIIAdQCGIJ4mAL4hYhJY-rbyiqrqCFo6ek50RoxmigAmBNZ2DvrO9MbA7l5wwDx2AUGh4SFQLDQIMkTNaa5EpKISUP7mEb3iPjUKABRW-gA2AK4QCq22-GgAlCQAfFAAnFsANINDFVW2o1AT03MKCDMAtlh2a8SbAEQ7zwch+yy9WANDEiNAuNJrN5lBrncHhsoDMEDlUAgIFl9v9hpVqkCzo9NjsPkwQgBuFhIWGEFCIai2CD+YAQTi8ZZjdouEqOAzFRhrHoSZqtJIgGRCdKEAB02gFTPZwuAa38grG4pSUs6KyUJiJBypwBmtkS3P+UlkCnFMhFVKyM3wEDGY38+Hwu352JEB1RUC1Or1rrdEhFfrtDu9PuU4sy+uDqOaNnsCmZHLcoZFgJAQZ94QjUHTqM+IhCKy+bqiMWNOlN5st1tt9sd4ud4bdHt1LozvT9IoDKJb4iUob+XaGOSj+VjypKPZ0JiT6JOgVTbqzwcJ32zjuEec74gacqg9L4AiJ4SYvKIN24e8EpHwVJpdLPjLj0pWGoA9M+yBBWssmKeGQIRYbTX8EUh3sMZnhkZ4nygV8zkWZYVgAWk2CF7lsb87z-ItAJFQc8lAgBGKCYLGFCoSQqA4IEdDfzQf9pFNLBgLw4AwIgoi3wAUVsWw4FsBQAEFbDQW4IAQIg9DYKBPHA55PHUQUEAqPoZBkdAEH8LApmgYA4CgMBon8G4IFpWwoAk8BoE8UjbE8EVqPPEUsMcnDcgQaMWIAJnYqAuJ4vifIAD0gQgkSgAAGPohJEsSZEdLAZiINAlPwkUgA)

Answer (score 0):

```
type PropType<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K];
type FooObjType<T> = { [M in keyof T]: Foo<T[M] extends ConfigItem<any, any> ? PropType<T[M], 'oneWay'> : any> }
type BarObjType<T> = { [M in keyof T]: Bar<T[M] extends ConfigItem<any, any> ? PropType<T[M], 'otherWay'> : any> }
```

*Note: I added a check to see if T[M] value extends ConfigItem just a precaution.*

These types will definition can help. The name of the types are arbitrary.

```
const configObject = {
    a: {
        oneWay: (value: string) => 99,
        otherWay: (value: number) => "99"
    } as ConfigItem<string, number>,


    b: {
        oneWay: (value: number) => undefined,
        otherWay: () => 99
    } as ConfigItem<number, undefined>
}
```

adding an conversion of each object in the `configObject`.

```
interface MyThing<T extends ConfigObject> {
    foos: FooObjType<T>,
    bars: BarObjType<T>
}
```

updated the `MyThing` interface

```
function createMyThing<T extends ConfigObject>(configObject: T): MyThing<T> {


    const keys = Object.keys(configObject);
    return {

        foos: keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
            return {
                ...acc,
                [key]: {
                    convert: configObject[key].oneWay
                }
            }
        }, {} as FooObjType<T>),

        bars: keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
            return {
                ...acc,
                [key]: {
                    deconvert: configObject[key].otherWay
                }
            };

        }, {} as BarObjType<T>),

    };
}
```

updated `createMyThing` function.

```
interface ConfigItem<P, Q> {
    oneWay: (value?: P) => Q;
    otherWay: (value?: Q) => P;
}
```

small modification to the function signatures in `ConfigItems` interface to allow empty params