# Is it possible to infer types from `any` types?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm wanting to do something like this:

```
interface Foo<T extends any>{
    a: string; 
    b: T; 
}

function createFunctions(items: Foo<any>[]) {
    return items.map(item => () => {
        return item.b; 
    }); 
}

const items = [
    {
        a: "hello",
        b: "foo"
    },
    {
        a: "world",
        b: 909
    }
]; 



const fns = createFunctions(items); 

const a2: string = fns[0]();  
const b2: string = fns[1](); //Should error - TypeScript should know it's a number
```

That is - I have a typed `Foo`, but that type can be anything.

I now have a list of these Foos, the list can be of all different types, but I know their types.

I then want to create a matching list of functions, with type enforcement on those functions.

The problem what I've got here - is that these functions will return as having 'any' type returns. How can I enforce the return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, each `b` property item in `items` can have a different type. To preserve each of the types, a possible solution is to work with an `items` tuple instead of an array and declare an explicit [mapped tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) return type for `createFunctions`:

```
interface Foo<T> { a: string; b: T; }

// we infer the items parameter via generic type parameter as tuple
// a mapped tuple type is used as return type
function createFunctions<T extends readonly Foo<any>[]>(items: T):
    { [K in keyof T]: () => T[K] extends Foo<any> ? T[K]["b"] : never } {
    return items.map(item => () => {
        return item.b;
    }) as any 
    // TS cannot properly infer return type here (generics + conditional types + mapped tuple)
    // alt cast: as unknown as { [K in keyof T]: () => T[K] extends Foo<any> ? T[K]["b"] : never }
}
```

The `items` tuple type is preserved via [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const items = [
    { a: "hello", b: "foo" },
    { a: "world", b: 909 }
] as const // <--- preserve the tuple type here

const fns = createFunctions(items); // readonly [() => "foo", () => 909]

const a2: string = fns[0](); // works
const b2: string = fns[1](); // error, 909 expected
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=38#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqA%20ZAb2TgC5kBnMKUAcwG5kAjcnRgXwChOB6H5UDGgDIAWwrIADnChxRESFGQA3YHGRgAnpJTTZ8xSQlgArpIA2EXvxMUU60XEk6AJhrOWN2%20xKgKTUCBeOpwwJiAIYMDoQQh%20cJCo4ZHRIBS4yBAAHpAgLr4QcC4x5ppomFhwIJp4ANoAungAFMBiFKwAlKScyL1EyLUA0gJBANYQmugwyDj15E0dyAC8BDhD9Zk5EHkSGNhVNcgA-DPrtQBETOcb5CAQysLsRD19fqaBIhDiAHSOki1iZYEBZA559cHIN4BIKtL7fJj0F69diLOASA7IPgzADKyAQVRA6DAUig6B0UFKIyESgAFtAIAAaSjoZAAdxQ%20KonC4nAQMSon3EywGSP6ZGQ5zp5nM6HOTJYEpgmHOyHYDNFxHF51Z6ApLjlzHIAE4AAxG1WcDZovH84lYrAAWidbJQrKqxLALMkfjsUAeGjp7gsKC0IV5tuQMDSwrihUSySi-IBXwoHUYWPixRAlNqIJWiuVTLzBFNRvq3D5aWJcAATOQqDQQLRhVGKLUTfUFun%20DqoKMKOGq8w65RqHQW2lagBGTtpzH8aCkqBAA)

[Here is an extended Playground that shows inference of multiple generic parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqAaZAVQD5kBvZOALmQGcwpQBzAbmQCMac2EbDkAvgCgRoSLEQoAShFoBXADZhcBEuSHJNyKAEYubDVqgAmPgeFCA9JeSgY0W5AC2tZAAc4UOE4jjkAN2A4ZDAATzcUDy8fPzhXMDk3BQgrGzlaFGCnODcIgBMQxOSQ8MzXKF85KBASiKEYORAEMGB0GoQKuEhURubWkFpcZAgAD0gQPPKIODy2hVC0TCw4EFCCFdDiAG0AXWIACmBnWi4ASipDTQotgGlbGoBrCFD0GGQcHZp90+QAXlIcLcdsMxhAJq4MNgNutVqQAPzIGTyJS4IFbABE7HROwIgJuOwxCGxpBoIAg-gcAnUWm0lWqjggLgAdNk3IdnH9SN9OdSaUY6TUyJc+TTdDQjoymewCMKRZoTOLnEyEDLZVphDSBD84pRVshrO8AMrIBArEDoMDuKDoCJQeb3exQZAAC2gEAItHQyAA7ihTfQhBYEG16AyXH9kFthRRqMh0a6FAp0OiCJw4zBMCmTTQAJw5wR4aOUGjo73oO15LNpvM5gi8OM5gAMOfRgiEwJ1wYGloNWAAtAOfShvStLWAvW4KhkoBSQq7CkkUGE6kIu6GYAMIx1pt1ei0Q+zGbRTmwDZ1ZiB7Vtuf905mCDfSE2czsRGvLXBTIjZIplPRGCATAECAchOOw0CkL8yAbrQWyNjs3ynjYZZQA8tCriGlrsF+SK-lgIFgdAeAEeBUCQdBAxbDoCEnvqNjQNaUBAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this works. Can you explain what the `as const` bit is?

Comment: You are welcome - added a link for const assertions in the answer. Basically with `as const`, the compiler assigns the most specific type possible to `items` (and marks it `readonly`, as now it is regarded immutable type-wise). For your case, also the side effect is interesting, that arrays like `items` with unknown count of items become readonly tuples (fix item count), so we can type each item individually. Drop the `as const` in the playground, and you see the changing types when hovering over.

Comment: Ok, thanks - if you're interested I have another question here - which I'm trying to use the learnings here to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58966420/access-generic-types-when-using-keyof